# HDD SAS vs SSD SATA vs NVME for MySQL database server

Tags: hard-drive, mysql, storage

I am configuring a high end server to run Linux with MariaDB / MySQL.  Performance is critical and as such I'll be maxing out RAM as far as possible.  Given this, my benchmarking suggests that the next bottleneck for my use case is disk IO. The server provider I am currently testing provides a few options for drives - on the face of it the HDD looks better as 12GBs > 6GBs ... however this does not feel right.  For reference the options I am provided with are:

SSD 3.84TB SATA 6Gbps

SSD 3.84TB NVMe

HDD 4TB SAS 12Gbps

(This is all information provided).

The cost or capacity of the drives is not a concern, all fall well within budget, and the server supports multiple of each.  The only remaining difference between the 3 is that the NVMe are not hot swappable - I can live without this.

Which of these will give the best IO in this scenario?

Comment: Did Google search (SAS vs NVMe) and found this. Not familiar with SAS server drives, so wanted to look it up. https://www.christitus.com/sata-vs-sas-vs-nvme/  Will database fit totally in RAM. If so that is best case.

Comment: Thanks- I am still unsure if SAS HDD is faster than SATA SSD (perhaps a better title for the question?).  The DB won't fit in RAM (it's 3TB currently) hence the need for fast IO

Comment: Not an answer but some discussion. Your issue is more database related, so that has somewhat different requirement. https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/hardware/processors-memory/1155354-linux-5-6-hwmon-changes-sent-in-with-big-amd-improvements/page2